# Запятая в сложном предложении с союзом и

Tags: пунктуация

> Но власть обманула и далеко не понятны перспективы.

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Но власть обманула,  и далеко не понятны перспективы.***

Запятая ставится в  ССП, союз НО общим элементом не является.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечания: 
2. **Противительный союз,** после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, **общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится:** Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.);

Примечание

Предложение желательно редактировать для улучшения стиля:

***Но власть обманула, а перспективы отнюдь не понятны.***

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз думал - вдруг НО является общим членом. По возможности, отредактируем.